# How to remove image blinking when using Tilt from Callisto for controls with images?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, tilt, callisto

In my Windows 8 C# app when I have **control containing image and I apply the Tilt from Callisto** on it, then **when this control is clicked for the first time, the image blinks**. It's quite disturbing especially when using it with custom "image buttons".

So is there a way how to make this control tiltable without image blinking?

For reproducing this issue just add this into new Windows 8 C# SplitApp project, add the Callisto NuGet package and comment the default GridView and SpliView.

```xml
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" effects:Tilt.IsTiltEnabled="True"
    Background="BlueViolet" Width="300" Height="100" >
    <Image Source="Assets/SmallLogo.png"/>
    <TextBlock Text="tap and watch the image blink" FontSize="20" />
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" effects:Tilt.IsTiltEnabled="True"
    Background="Crimson" Width="300" Height="100" Grid.Row="1" >
    <Image Source="Assets/SmallLogo.png"/>
    <TextBlock Text="tap and watch the image blink" FontSize="20"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [workaround](https://github.com/timheuer/callisto/issues/194#issuecomment-22725313): add `CacheMode="BitmapCache"` to `<Image>`.